# MAGENTO - SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '_store.core_resource'

Tags: mysql, magento

i think im with a big problem.
I deleted the files of mysql :

in directory:
/var/lib/mysql/

that files:
ib_logfile1 
ib_logfile0 
ibdata1

cause it was a big file and i googled it i found to del that. But now magento 1.7 show thats erro:

```
There has been an error processing your request

Error in file: "/var/www/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/install-    1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '_store.core_resource' doesn't exist

Trace:
#0 /var/www/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645):     Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /var/www/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.6.0.2')
#2 /var/www/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.6.0.2')
#3 /var/www/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /var/www/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /var/www/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App- >_initModules()
#6 /var/www/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /var/www/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}

Error log record number: 667552580198

Magento is a trademark of Magento Inc. Copyright © 2012 Magento Inc.
```

got any solution ?

THANKS

Answer (score 1):

You have deleted some of the plugins that connect to the database to check that tables exist or not. Accidentally you have deleted those files. So magento is unable to connect to the database.

A tough solution (may work or may not) is: Install another magento in the same root folder by pointing to the new database. After successful installation, copy the files from this new magento to the old magneto application. Check it by deleting the files in cache folder.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. I did not delete the same files, but after I restarted MySQL the error went away. It doesn't really help explain where the error came from, but it worked in my case.